# Creating a div with a variable vertical height

Tags: css, html, expand

as per screenshot attached:

[image: http://oi53.tinypic.com/m8jszm.jpg]

I want to create a `<div>` that is positioned "x" pixels from the top, but essentially "expands" vertically to fit whatever is in a given tab as well as horizontally the width of the whole page with a solid colour. Essentially a `<div>` that ignores the other `<div>`'s. Screenshot explains what I mean better. How do I make such a `<div>` layout?

Comment: You are probably looking for a Sticky Footer (as its called in webdesigner language)

Comment: It would be useful to see some HTML/CSS to know how you're structuring the page.

Answer (score 0):

A sticky footer looks to me what you are looking for. This means you have a content area that is either the entire screen or if it has more contents, fits the content. The footer is either on the bottom of the screen or on the bottom of the content

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

or search for stickyfooter on Stack Overflow

And abit of html to get you started

http://jsbin.com/emufot/8/

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS should do the job for you as if you don't set a height for a div, it will automatically expand to fit its content. Here is some code I knocked up quickly which will display the idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".css"/>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.topstuff {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.contentContainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.content {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="topstuff"></div>
<div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent semper placerat ligula volutpat aliquam. Maecenas vulputate, nibh at iaculis placerat, ligula nisl sodales odio, quis adipiscing purus dolor venenatis nunc. Proin vehicula rhoncus eros tristique aliquet. Vivamus faucibus hendrerit orci eget egestas. Nulla commodo lectus vitae nunc condimentum pharetra. Donec mattis nulla orci. Proin tortor nulla, varius at mollis ac, vestibulum vel leo. Cras ut rutrum sem. Sed vulputate nisi sed leo aliquam ac fermentum tellus porta. Phasellus quis purus et purus sollicitudin tristique a quis sem. Nunc malesuada, eros ac venenatis consequat, erat elit viverra sem, vitae commodo justo orci nec neque. Proin sed aliquam tellus. In tincidunt urna sit amet felis lobortis fringilla elementum massa egestas.</p>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just replace the 'lorerm ipsum etc' content with whatever you want to see the containing div change size.

Good Luck.